# what is password encryption method in joomla 1.5.26?

Tags: php, html, joomla

As I am doing the webservice for an mobile app for which the site has been developed in joomla 1.5.26 and I need to know how to encrypt the password through webservice for user login.

Comment: Encrypting a password via a web service sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Check [this related pr](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/1745)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, well done for using the most recent version of your Joomla series, doesn't happen a lot. Please do consider upgrading to Joomla 2.5+ as 1.5 has security issues and is not supported anymore ;)

I'm not sure about older versions but 1.5+ uses MD5 and Salting.

It's stored in the database like so:

```
{hash}:{salt}
```

and can be generated like so:

```
md5( $password.$salt );
```

To get a an example of how the password is generated, have a look [here](http://www.subclosure.com/generate-new-joomla-1-5-md5salt-encrypted-passwords-to-store-in-database.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not sure Joomla 1.5 uses salting. But it is MD5 encryption.

Comment: it doesn't match the password that stored in the database.

Comment: @kmas - Joomla 1.5 does use salting as md5 isn't considered secure on it's own

Comment: @Jack - sorry small typo there, I meant **isn't** ;)

Comment: md5 + salt is used getrandomgeneration function where i get doubt with the variables. can I get the encryption method of joomla of that randomgeneration function in detail.